# How to display an image at full width in Qt QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing

I'm using this code to load image and show in screen.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered(void){

    QString fileName;
    fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
        tr("Open Image"), "C:\\Users", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)"));


    qim.load( fileName );
    pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage( qim );
    scene.clear();
    scene.addPixmap( pixmap );
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(&scene);

}
```

But when I upload a small picture, it doesn't fill the screen and it appears in its original size. As you can see:

[image]

The desired screen should look like this:

[image]

(I am trying to make an application similar to [this site](https://setosa.io/ev/image-kernels/). Grayscale doesn't matter.)

image used:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
qim.load( fileName );
pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage( qim );

QPixmap scaled_img = pixmap.scaled(this->width(), this->height(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

scene.clear();
scene.addPixmap( scaled_img );
ui->graphicsView->setScene(&scene);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [fitInView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView-2) with [Qt::AspectRatioMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AspectRatioMode-enum) on your `ui->graphicsView` object.

Comment: How should I use it with these? I'm new to c ++.

Comment: I don't know how to use it.

Comment: The link points to a function signature like this:
`void QGraphicsView::fitInView(const QGraphicsItem *item, Qt::AspectRatioMode aspectRatioMode = Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio)
`

This means that an object of type `QGraphicsView` (like your `ui->graphicsView`) has a method `fitInView`. So it used like `ui->graphicsView->fitInView(..)`. 
You will give the proper `const QGraphicsItem *` as the first argument and `Qt::AspectRatioMode` as the second. It's all in the signature.